# How to connect to a sqlite database file in the internal storage with Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm using Android Studio, and I want to connect to a SQLite database that I have on the Internal Storage, without copying it to another location.

I have the code in java, but I can't find how to do it on Android. All that I could find was using SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open it directly use the [SQLiteDatabase **openDatabase**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#openDatabase(java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)) method.

e.g.

```
    SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("the path",null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    SQLiteDatabase mydatabase2 = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(new File("the path"),SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE); //<<<<< REQUIRES API 27+
```

You can also use **SQLiteOpenHelper** with the 2nd paramater as the path (I believe in that case the Context could be null (haven't tried this way)).

- obviously appropriate permissions need to be granted

Comment: Thanks for your answer, all the examples that I had was with SQLiteOpenHelper.